# problem finding links in all li tag under ul tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the links in all li tags under the ul tag

HTML code:

```
<div id="chapter-list" class="sbox" style="">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="https://example.com/manga/name/2">
<div class="chpbox">
<span class="chapternum">
Chapter 2 </span>
</div>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://example.com/manga/name/1">
<div class="chpbox">
<span class="chapternum">
Chapter 1 </span>
</div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The code I wrote:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_page = requests.get('https://example.com/manga/name/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')
chapters = soup.find('div', {"id": "chapter-list"})

children = chapters.findChildren("ul" , recursive=False) # when printed, it gives the the whole ul content

for litag in children.find('li'):
    print(litag.find("a")["href"])
```

When I try to print the li tags links, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\0.py", line 12, in <module>
    for litag in children.find('li'):
  File "C:\Users\hs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2289, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to find the `ul` in the chapter list. And then `find_all` to find the list items in the `ul`. Finally, use `find_all` again to find the links in each list item and print the URL. Details of these two methods can be found in [find and find_all method documentation on bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree). You can use the `get_text()` after searching by the class `chapternum` on each link to get the link's text like `Chapter 1`. Searching by class be found in [bs4 documentation for searching element by class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

**(Updated) Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div id="chapter-list" class="sbox" style="">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://example.com/manga/name/2">
                <div class="chpbox">
<span class="chapternum">
Chapter 2 </span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://example.com/manga/name/1">
                <div class="chpbox">
<span class="chapternum">
Chapter 1 </span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
chapters = soup.find('div', {"id": "chapter-list"})

list_items = chapters.find('ul').find_all('li')

for list_item in list_items:
    for link in list_item.find_all('a'):
        title = link.find('span', class_='chapternum').get_text().strip()
        href = link.get("href")
        print(f"{title}: {href}")
```

**Output:**

```
Chapter 2: https://example.com/manga/name/2
Chapter 1: https://example.com/manga/name/1
```

**References:**

- [find and find_all method documentation on bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree)
- [bs4 documentation for searching element by class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Is there any way I can get a specific link? For example, getting the link of chapter 1, and then the link of chapter 2

Comment: You can use the `get_text()` on each link to get the link's text like `Chapter 1`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I just need the text within the `class="chapternum"`, I don't need the `class="chapterdate"`, is there anyway to filter it out?

Comment: Updated the answer again. Added searching by the `class` = `chapternum`.